# Gatling POST request

Tags: load-testing, gatling

```
  class PostRequest extends Simulation {

  val httpProtocol = http
  .baseUrl("https://myurl.com")
  .inferHtmlResources()
  .acceptHeader("text/html,...v=b3")
  .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
  .acceptLanguageHeader("en-GB,....")
  .upgradeInsecureRequestsHeader("1")
  .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 ....Safari/537.36")

  val uuid = Iterator.continually(Map("val" -> java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString()))

  val scn = 
  exec(_.set("uuid",uuid))
  scenario("PostRequest")
    .feed(uuid)
    .exec(http("request_0")
    .post("/path/")
    .body(StringBody("""
          {
              "Id": "${uuid}",
              "one": 
                {
                  "id": "${uuid}",
                  "channel": "EMAIL",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-01-22.23.23.123456",
                }
    }
  """))
     )

  setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
    }
```

while compiling, i am getting error

```
value inject is not a member of io.gatling.core.structure.ChainBuilder
setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1))).protocols(httpProtocol)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `scn` holds the value of `exec(_.set("uuid",uuid))`, which is a `ChainBuilder` instance, which you can't call `inject` on. Some curly brackets solve the problem, like this:

```
  val scn = {
    exec(_.set("uuid", uuid))
    scenario("PostRequest")
      .feed(uuid)
      .exec(http("request_0")
        .post("/path/")
        .body(StringBody(
          """
            {
              "Id": "${uuid}",
              "one":
                {
                  "id": "${uuid}",
                  "channel": "EMAIL",
                  "timeStamp": "2018-05-01-22.23.23.123456",
                }
            }
          """
        ))
      )
  }
```